# How to Create a Date Range for Postgres In Node js Using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model where one of the attributes: `availability` is an array of timestamp ranges `tstzrange[]`.

```
@Column({
type: DataType.ARRAY(DataType.RANGE(DataType.DATE))
```

})

My question is, how do I create a value of that type to store it in the db?
I tried something like:

```
availability:[[new Date(), new Date()],[new Date(), new Date()],[new Date(), new Date()]]
```

But I got an error saying this is of type `text[]`.
These are the docs I'm following:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
availability:[new Date(), new Date()]
```

Range can have only one lower and upper limit.